# Changing Pixel Color in Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I want to be able to modify the color displayed in the video capture.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import cv2
import numpy as np

Y_MIN = 80
Y_MAX = 255
Cr_MIN = 135
Cr_MAX = 180
Cb_MIN = 85
Cb_MAX = 135
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
flag, frame = cap.read()
YCrCb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
cv2image = cv2.inRange(YCrCb,(Y_MIN,Cr_MIN,Cb_MIN),(Y_MAX,Cr_MAX,Cb_MAX))
cv2.imshow('frame', cv2image)
```

Doing this, I open the capture device, convert it to YCR_CB color space, and then run it through the inRange function based on my variables to do a basic test to look for skin color. My question is, can I change the output color from just black for background, and white for the flagged 'skin' areas to something like green for the flagged areas? After being able to select the color myself, I'd like to try and incorporate the tkinter.colorchooser to allow for easy choosing.

Comment: Which modules have your imported?

Comment: Tkinter, cv2, and numpy

Comment: You cannot perform the task just by the script above. This is indeed more work than this IMO.

Comment: I added some more code to make it display the first frame.  So from that, I want to choose another color other than white for example green, and eventually use the color chooser.

Comment: You can use `tkinter.colorchooser` for color choosing.

Comment: Yeah I found the colorchooser my main issue is I'm not sure how to work it into the above code since a color is not being chosen it just defaults to white as the pixels in the image that are within the parameters in the cv2.inRange part.